# Render a large list in html

Tags: javascript, html

When rendering all elements in the DOM the browser becomes laggy. I used virtual list but the problem with virtual list is when you scroll too fast (especially on mobile phones) the screen becomes white.

So now what i'm doing is to keep a limited amount of elements in DOM when user scrolls to the bottom, remove the nodes from DOM and render the next elements. if the user scrolls to top the reverse. but the problem with this approach is - the scrolling experience is not that great.

does anybody have a better solution ?
should i keep this solution or is there any better way to approach this ?

Comment: Keep all the elements in the DOM, and control visibility instead of removing/recreating elements.

Comment: @Teemu, with all nodes in DOM do the browser become laggy ?

Comment: @Teemu it doesn't solve the problem of slow initial build. i spent a 6 months programming a good virtual table with variable row height, it's not a trivial task. the fixed row height is relatively easy

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev, yeah man. i been stuck with this for few days. every solution has it's own problems.

Comment: Are you using pure html/javascript, or a framework like angular?

Comment: @Pieterjan, i'm using vue. to be exact nuxt 3

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Table handling is much slower than list handling, I'm not sure of what OP really has, thought, I assumed `menu`/`ul`/`ol`.

Comment: @Teemu a list = a table with 1 column, the same problem

Comment: @Teemu, i'm rendering a large dataset. not in in `li` tag but `div` tag. i'm sorry for the list confusion

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [page unresponsive due to large amounts of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68400772/383904)

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Like always, we shouldn't assume anything considering the lacking information, it's just better to ask. This time we both had incorrect assumption.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, i already tried your 2nd example but the problem with that still stands. it's not that memory consuming when the rendering element that are just text. but when you render a element with svg and image and lot of child nodes you can notice the browser lag when you keep scrolling. and as for pagination it is the best solution but the requirement is list. an infinite list.

Comment: @MuhammedJabir Take a look at [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), it might give you some ideas.

Comment: An idea would be to use the [*Example 2 (that uses IntersectionObserver API)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68400772/383904) but remove the elements once they leave the viewport (and after some safe amount of offset). Once an element is removed, you could eventually add that element's height to a spacer element which is a first and empty element in the list (which job is to preserve the scroll position)... Some issue though would be making it work as responsive.... Seems indeed a complicated task to achieve But I've seen it done. Hard to answer without further details.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, i'm doing something like this, but without adding height to space bar. i'm getting the last item and some offset and i'm scrolling to the last item when adding the next elements. i think in my requirement adding height to space would complicate things because each item's height varies.

Comment: @MuhammedJabir Don't know if I would bother of the screen being blank for .15 seconds while scrolling. The angular team built a [directive for virtual scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview) which works in an optimal way, and there too the list is blank for 0.05 seconds. I see that there's several libraries for this: [example](https://primevue.org/virtualscroller/)

Comment: @Pieterjan, vue has something like this [virtual list](https://vueuse.org/core/useVirtualList/). but the problem with virtual list is when the elements has rich UI elements. the screen goes blank for longer.

Comment: You have to create your table in a canvas. It won't be easy, but when done, you will be able to scroll into hundreds of thousands of records. Because there is no DOM refresh.

Comment: @NVRM thanks, I'll try this. But can you elaborate a bit more, please ?

Comment: It's about the canvas technology: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D AND https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText . Here is a plugin that seems to do this https://github.com/el/canvas-table#readme . Example usage https://codesandbox.io/s/canvas-table-6q65o

Comment: Please provide some codes with a loop that create some HTML DOM, and explain why it can't handle thousands of records. Then your question would be absolutely interesting and valid.